# Set of wildcard matches from variable names

Tags: wildcard, stata

I have a set of variables, say `varA`, `varB`, and `varC`.

How can I loop over *only* the postfixes `A`, `B`, and `C`?

I know I can get all of the matching variables as follows:

```
des var*

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
varA            float   %9.0g                 
varB            float   %9.0g                 
varC            float   %9.0g
```

However, is there a way to extract only the matching component and loop over it?

The ideal code would be something like the one below:

```
des var*

foreach postfix in `r(wildcardmatches)' {
    display "`postfix'"
}
```

If the set `r(wildcardmatches)` existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
* sandbox 
clear
set obs 1 
foreach v in varA varB varC { 
    gen `v' = 42 
}

* core idea and verification
unab wanted : var* 
local wanted : subinstr local wanted "var" "", all

display "`wanted'"
A B C
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ds` command can also be used:

```
clear
set obs 1

foreach v in varA varB varC { 
    generate `v' = 42 
}

ds var*
foreach x in `"`= subinstr("`r(varlist)'", "var", " ", .)'"' {
    display "`x'"
}

 A  B  C
```

EDIT NJC:

```
foreach v of var var* { 
    display "`: subinstr local v "var" "", all'" 
}
```

would seem to be the same nice idea simplified. That is, if you are going to loop over a wildcard varlist, you can loop directly with `foreach` and said varlist. You don't need `ds` to push the varlist into `r(varlist)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get only the matching component directly, but this workaround gets it indirectly:

```
local prefix="var"
foreach variable of varlist `prefix'* {
    local postfix=subinstr("`variable'", "`prefix'", "", .)
    // Work with postfix
}
```